# How to expand system partition? [Xiaomi Mi 9]

Tags: file-system, partitions, system, xiaomi, miui

How to expand system partition?
I'd need at least ~600MB more for OpenGapps package I'd like.

Many thanks in advance!

Here's log from `parted`

```
cepheus:/ # parted /dev/block/sde
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/block/sde
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: WDC SDINDDH4-64G (scsi)
Disk /dev/block/sde: 6442MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name           Flags
 1      24.6kB  57.3kB  32.8kB               multiimgoem
 2      57.3kB  90.1kB  32.8kB               multiimgqti
 3      90.1kB  123kB   32.8kB               secdata
 4      123kB   156kB   32.8kB               limits
 5      156kB   262kB   106kB                bk41
 6      262kB   393kB   131kB                qupfw
 7      393kB   524kB   131kB                qupfwbak
 8      524kB   786kB   262kB                apdp
 9      786kB   1049kB  262kB                msadp
10      1049kB  1180kB  131kB                vbmeta
11      1180kB  1311kB  131kB                storsec
12      1311kB  1573kB  262kB                bk42
13      1573kB  1835kB  262kB                devcfg
14      1835kB  2097kB  262kB                devcfgbak
15      2097kB  2621kB  524kB                aop
16      2621kB  3146kB  524kB                aopbak
17      3146kB  3670kB  524kB                uefivarstore
18      3670kB  4194kB  524kB                catefv
19      4194kB  5243kB  1049kB               cmnlib
20      5243kB  6291kB  1049kB               cmnlibbak
21      6291kB  7340kB  1049kB               cmnlib64
22      7340kB  8389kB  1049kB               cmnlib64bak
23      8389kB  9437kB  1049kB               bk43
24      9437kB  10.5MB  1049kB               keymaster
25      10.5MB  11.5MB  1049kB               keymasterbak
26      11.5MB  12.6MB  1049kB               bluetooth
27      12.6MB  13.6MB  1049kB               dip
28      13.6MB  14.7MB  1049kB               catecontentfv
29      14.7MB  23.1MB  8389kB               bk44
30      23.1MB  25.2MB  2097kB               bk44
31      25.2MB  27.3MB  2097kB               cateloader
32      27.3MB  29.4MB  2097kB               uefisecapp
33      29.4MB  31.5MB  2097kB               uefisecappbak
34      31.5MB  33.6MB  2097kB               toolsfv
35      33.6MB  35.7MB  2097kB               abl
36      35.7MB  37.7MB  2097kB               ablbak
37      37.7MB  41.9MB  4194kB               tz
38      41.9MB  46.1MB  4194kB               tzbak
39      46.1MB  50.3MB  4194kB               bk45
40      50.3MB  58.7MB  8389kB               fsg
41      58.7MB  67.1MB  8389kB               spunvm
42      67.1MB  75.5MB  8389kB               hyp
43      75.5MB  83.9MB  8389kB               hypbak
44      83.9MB  101MB   16.8MB               gsort
45      101MB   134MB   33.6MB               dtbo
46      134MB   201MB   67.1MB               ifaa
47      201MB   268MB   67.1MB               logo
48      268MB   336MB   67.1MB  ext4         dsp
49      336MB   470MB   134MB                boot
50      470MB   493MB   23.1MB               bk47
51      493MB   671MB   178MB                core_nhlos
52      671MB   1007MB  336MB                modem          msftdata
53      1007MB  2617MB  1611MB  ext2         vendor
54      2617MB  6375MB  3758MB  ext2         system
```

Comment: do yourself a favor and try on emmc image first. that doesn't look promising. where is userdata partition? why don't you install pico instead? that apps can installed from google play, no need to increase system partition

Comment: Have you checked if simply deleting installed bloatware from the system partitions could free up enough space. Also I recommend to install only the "mini" OpenGApps package. Everything else can be downloaded from PlayStore and installed onto the user data partition. Installing a larger OpenGApps packae onto the system partition and later update parts of it from Play Store just wastes space on your system partition as you them have it twice: the old unused one on system and the updated one on user.